# No HDMI Output to a TV from PS3

Tags: ps3

I have a TV and a monitor that are both HD. I have been switching both my PS3 and Xbox 360 between the two using HDMI ports successfully for the past 10 months. Last night my wife watched a Blu Ray movie disc while the PS3 was plugged into the TV. This morning, the TV no longer gets a signal through the HDMI port.

The HDMI port on the TV works: I can plug my 360 in and everything is fine.
The HDMI port on the PS3 and the HDMI cable work: I can plug my PS3 into my monitor and all is well.

I can plug in the AV cables from the PS3 to the TV and that works. The only problem is connecting the PS3 to the TV using HDMI.

I have tried holding down the power button on the PS3 to automatically reset the output. The TV shows 'No Signal.'

I have tried plugging in the AV cable and the HDMI cable at the same time, switching the TV to AV, and then manually changing the output to HDMI. When I switch the TV to HDMI it shows 'No Signal'.

I have tried connecting the PS3 to my monitor using HDMI and manually changing the resolution (1080p, 1080i, 720, 480) and then tried plugging it into the TV. The TV shows 'No Signal.'

I have tried unplugging both the PS3 and the TV and then retrying all of the above steps. The TV shows 'No Signal.'

Does anyone have any other ideas?

**EDIT :** I had not unplugged the HDMI cord from last night when I tried this morning.  I tried all three HDMI ports on the TV, none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer was determined by a helpful user on the Playstation support forums: http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Support/No-HDMI-Output-to-one-TV/td-p/41669633/highlight/false

> It appears that the HDMI port on the TV is only partially damaged.  The XBox 360 doesn't notice the problem, but the PS3 does.  The PS3 is much more particular about the HDMI interfaces that it connects to, because is is designed to resist attempts at digital video piracy.  The XBox 360 is not.  If the PS3 works with the monitor, but not with the TV, then chances are there is something wrong with the TV HDMI port, but it is a function that the XBox doesn't use, or doesn't care about.

Comment: *"..because is is designed to resist attempts at digital video piracy. The XBox 360 is not."* - I doubt that's true.  They both use the same transport-encryption protocol, [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection), which defines when communication to a host (TV) should fail.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft IIRC, the PS3 outputs everything (even gameplay) under HDCP when you use HDMI, while with the Xbox 360, it only kicks on when you try to view video content. So perhaps it could be that if you never try to view video content on your 360, this particular issue would never surface.